# Read and delete files from folder

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to write a program to read each file from a folder and after the contents in the file are read the file should get deleted. I could write programs to read the files from a folder and delete files from a folder separately, but couldn't integrate both of them in one program.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far to try and accomplish the task.

Comment: If you're havin a problem with your code, you'll need to show us some code so we get an understanding of what you're doing

Comment: If you have a program to read the files and another to delete the files, you can just put everything from `public static void main()` into a new `public void run()`, and then call `A.run()` and `B.run()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Java Code I wrote and tested. It works fine.

It will first list all the files in the specified directory and all levels of sub-directories inside it.

Then it will read all files in specified directory & all levels of sub-directories inside it one by one, then delete them once it has finished reading a file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RecursiveFileDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDir = new File("D:\\test"); // current directory
        File[] fileList = displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
        readAndDeleteFiles(fileList);
    }

    public static File[] displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        File[] files = null;
        try {
            files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    //recursive call to fetch file list in all levels of sub-directories
                    displayDirectoryContents(file); 
                } else {
                    System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return files;
    }
    public static void readAndDeleteFiles(File[] fileList){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        for(File file : fileList){
            if (!file.isDirectory()){
                try {

                    String sCurrentLine;

                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getCanonicalPath()));
                    if (br != null){
                        System.out.println("Reading file : " + file.getCanonicalPath());

                        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                        }

                        br.close();
                        System.out.println("Finished reading file : " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    }

                    //deleting file
                    if(file.delete()){
                        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath() + " is deleted!");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath() + " could not be deleted!"); 
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else{
                //recursive call to fetch file list in all levels of sub-directories and then read & delete each of them
                readAndDeleteFiles(file.listFiles());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following method:

```
 public static void listFilesForFolder(File folder) {
     for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

        try {

            File newFile = new File(fileEntry.getName()));

            /*read the newFile whatever way you want to*/

           /* then after reading delete it */

            if(newFile.delete()){
              System.out.println("File is deleted");
            }else {
              System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            };


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }
    }
```

You can Put the folder name in the following way:

```
File newFile = new File("C://path//to//file//" + fileEntry.getName());
```